# MySQL Select Sub-Queries or Joins

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with a USERS (doctors and nurses), PATIENTS and ASSIGNMENTS table:

```
USERS (id, etc.)
PATIENTS (id, doctorid, etc.)
ASSIGNMENTS (id, patientid, doctorid, nurseid, etc.)
```

When a DOCTOR is logged in, he needs to see his list of PATIENTS and the NURSE or NURSES assigned to that PATIENT. The result should look something like this:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+
| patient first name |  patient last name |  assigned nurses  |
+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+
| john               |  doe               |  nurse 1, nurse 2 |
| jim                |  jones             |  nurse 7          |
| john               |  doe               |  nurse 4, nurse 5 |
| jim                |  jones             |  nurse 3          |
| jim                |  jones             |  nurse 6          |
+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+
```

How would I write the sql to return this data?

My sql is returning the all the NURSES for each row:

```
SELECT a.id, a.doctorid, a.firstname, a.lastname, GROUP_CONCAT(distinct c.firstname, ' ', c.lastname) as assignednurse

FROM dependents a

        JOIN (
            SELECT ass.id, ass.dependentid, ass.nurseid
            FROM assignments ass
        ) b ON (a.doctorid = 22)

        JOIN (
            u.id, u.doctorid, u.firstname, u.lastname
            FROM users u
            GROUP BY u.id
        ) c ON (c.id = b.nurseid)

        GROUP BY a.id
```

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: Your query includes a table called `dependents` - is that the same as `patients`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your join condition to `assignments` does not include a field from `assignments`, so it is essentially a cross/cartesian join. Additionally, you are doing subqueries where these don't appear to be necessary - this shouldn't affect the values returned, but may retard performance, and will make maintenance harder. Instead, try:

```
SELECT a.id, 
       a.doctorid, 
       a.firstname, 
       a.lastname, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(distinct c.firstname, ' ', c.lastname) as assignednurse
FROM patients a
LEFT JOIN assignments b ON a.id = b.patientid
LEFT JOIN users c ON c.id = b.nurseid
WHERE a.doctorid = 22
GROUP BY a.id
```

Comment: thx @markbannister...this fixes the nurse issue, but it's only returning one patient row...this doctor has more than one patient in my database

Comment: @user2401763: I have changed the joins to left joins - try again. If you still see only one row returned, try running `select count(*) from patients where doctorid = 22` and let me know what number is returned.